# Setting permissions for the folder using wix

Tags: permissions, wix

i'm new to wix installer process to create msi after build the application.
i'm going to create one msi. while installing that msi, it prefers location as "C:/Program Files(x86)/Folder1/Folder2". and after installation Folder2 will contain application dll, exe files and so on.

**I can launch my application from default master admin user account(e.g. user1).**

if my system has another user account which has Standard privileges(e.g. user2), **I can't launch my application from this user account.**

```
so problem is user2 is not having permission to access "C:/Program Files(x86)/Folder1/Folder2" this path.
```

how can i set this in wix before installation.? is it possible to set before creation of msi installer for my application?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See my answer on this thread, this should answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976360/wix-custom-action-execute-cmd-not-working/13976864#13976864

Comment: Thank you Natalie Carr. but my que is it will create new folder and permissions? or we can give permissions for existing folder??

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="Folder1ProgFiles" Name="Folder1">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Folder2">
             <Component......./>
          </Directory>

and Folder2 directory has nearly 40 components. now i've to give permission for Folder2 directory. i no need to create new folder.
can you get my point dude? clear me...

Comment: From experience I have had to set permissions on all of my files also so try that as well. That code should just add the permissions to whatever directory u have specified - have you tried it? If so what exactly happened?